# Google recaptcha v3 success issue

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have very basic form to test google recaptcha v3, but always got success false.

Here is my HTML code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google recapcha v3</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=my_site_key">      
    </script>
    <script>
      grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      grecaptcha.execute('my_site_key', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
        var recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
        recaptchaResponse.value = token;
      });
  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Google reCAPTHA Test</h1>
    <form id="testform" action="contact.php" method="post" >
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" size="40"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK"><br><br>
      <input type="hidden" value="" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And Here is contact.php code

```
<?php

$recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$recaptcha_secret = 'my_secret_key';
$recaptcha_response = $_POST['recaptcha_response'];

//Make and decode POST request:
$recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url . '?secret=' . $recaptcha_secret . '&response=' . $recaptcha_response);
$recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha);

if($recaptcha->success==true){
   if($recaptcha->score >= 0.5) {
       echo 'Pass !';
   } else {
       echo 'Spammer';
   }  
} else {
  echo 'Connection failed';
}
?>
```

I always got 'Connection failed' in the result.

I am sure I have the site key and secret key correctly.  Just don't know what could be wrong for this ?

Comment: First do a debug dump output of what `$recaptcha` has in it like `print_r($recaptcha);` or `var_dump($recaptcha);` (whichever you prefer the output of). Then make sure you are referencing the right variable for your `if true` condition.

Comment: You could also use https://github.com/google/recaptcha as your library for interacting with recaptcha in PHP. The key point is either sending vars as POST, or `urlencode()` the values in your GET params.

Comment: Lastly, have you made sure that `$_POST['recaptcha_response']` actually contains the monster token string as set by the javascript you have going? You should debug/echo that out too to make sure.